# Simple PLPythonu function not visible

Tags: postgresql, postgres-plpython

I'm working with PLPython3u in Postgres 9.6. I have installed the extra package under Ubuntu and this code runs:

```
response = db.query([[
   CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION bytea_import() RETURNS void as $$
      print("foo")


  $$ LANGUAGE plpython3u;
  ]])

response = db.query("SELECT bytea_import();")
```

The second line runs the code without error but if I look in Postgres after running this code, with `\df <schema>.*` the function does not exist. Once defined, should the function not be in the database?

```
                   List of functions
Schema | Name | Result data type | Argument data types | Type 
--------+------+------------------+---------------------+------
(0 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

The function can be viewed with `\df+ bytea_import`. And it can be dropped with `DROP FUNCTION bytea_import();`. If there are parameters, these need to be listed in the DROP FUNCTION as well.